How to handle Clerk sign-in/factor-one page in nextjs?
I'm currently integrating Clerk for authentication in my Next.js project. I followed the documentation to implement the first factor authentication, but I keep encountering the following error when
demo
How to handle Clerk sign-in/factor-one page in nextjs ?
help me handle clerk factor one page

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

the problem was the app routes:
wrong routing:

(auth)/sign-in/page.tsx
(auth)/sign-in/page.tsx

Correct routing:

(auth)/sign-in/[[...sign-in]]/page.tsx
(auth)/sign-in/[[...sign-up]]/page.tsx

